# Excel Formula to count all items in a group to see if the status is an Open status

Tags: excel, pivot-table, formula

I am working in Excel 2016. I am trying to figure out how many projects I have that have not had any part of it started. For instance if my project id is 203784 and it has 3 parts to it where 2 are Complete and 1 was Not Started. I would not want to count that. If the project had 3 parts and 2 were Not Started 1 was assigned. I would want to count that as 1. Thank you in advance you your assistance.

```
+----+------------+------------------+-------------+
|    |     A      |        B         |      C      |
+----+------------+------------------+-------------+
|  1 | Project ID | Position         | Status      |
|  2 | 203784     | Staff            | Complete    |
|  3 | 203784     | Staff            | Complete    |
|  4 | 203784     | Staff            | Not Started |
|  5 | 203785     | Maintenance      | Complete    |
|  6 | 203785     | Maintenance      | In Progress |
|  7 | 203786     | Grounds          | Complete    |
|  8 | 203787     | Nurse            | Complete    |
|  9 | 203788     | Teacher          | Complete    |
| 10 | 203788     | Teacher          | Complete    |
| 11 | 203788     | Teacher          | Complete    |
| 12 | 203789     | Transportation   | Complete    |
| 13 | 203789     | Transportation   | Complete    |
| 14 | 203789     | Transportation   | Complete    |
| 15 | 203790     | Evacuation       | Complete    |
| 16 | 203790     | Evacuation       | Complete    |
| 17 | 203791     | Implementation   | Complete    |
| 18 | 203792     | Knowledge Base   | Not Started |
| 19 | 203792     | Knowledge Base   | Not Started |
| 20 | 203793     | Janitor          | Not Started |
| 21 | 203794     | Public Relations | In Progress |
| 22 | 203795     | HR               | Complete    |
| 23 | 203796     | Admin            | Complete    |
+----+------------+------------------+-------------+
```

In this example. I would only want the count to show a total of 2. For project numbers 203792 and 203793.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to add a column (say Count) populated as:

```
 =COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,C:C,"Complete")+COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,C:C,"In Progress")
```

and then create a PivotTable with `Count` as Filters and `Project ID` for Rows. Select `0` for the filter.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't think of using countifs like that. But it makes total sense.